# SignUpCallback Error Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I keep having issues with creating my user signup with parse. For some reason I keep getting the following error: [image: screenshot] . I have no clue why, I am pretty sure I am doing everything right (This is my first time using parse).

```
 public void signUp() {

        myName = name.getText().toString();
        myEmail = email.getText().toString();
        myPass = pass.getText().toString();
        myRepass = repass.getText().toString();
        myInterests = interests.getText().toString();

        if (myPass.compareTo(myRepass) == 0) {
            if (myPass.length() >= 6) {
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(myEmail);
                user.setPassword(myPass);
                user.setEmail(myEmail);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            misMatch();
                        } else {
                            // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                            // to figure out what went wrong
                            showShortAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                showShortAlert();
            }
        } else {

            misMatch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us the code for `SignUpCallback` where you have declared it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue, essentially what I need to do is :

```
  public void done(ParseUser parseUser, com.parse.ParseException e) {
```